# Gun laws in the United States by state

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the meaning of the preposition "*by*" in the title of this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_laws_in_the_United_States_by_state):

> Gun laws in the United States by state

Does the "*by*" above have the same meaning as in "*gun laws enacted* ***by*** *the state*"?  Or is the usage in the wikipedia article an error?

Comment: [by](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/by) - 3.3 Identifying a parameter: _a breakdown of employment figures by age and occupation_.

Comment: It refers to the arrangement of the table in the lower section of the wiki article. The table is organized by state.

Comment: Note that your rewording "enacted by *the* state" introduces a very different meaning. Structurally, each of the 50 states that compose the United States are independently organized and have their own laws. The nation has laws that apply nation-wide, but only to the extent that they are not overruled by state law. Adding *the* to the sentence changes the implication from many "state" entities, each with their own laws, to a single "state" (probably the nation?) with gun laws. Which then makes the "by" meaningless because a singular state should not have conflicting laws.

Comment: Not sure I said that right, let me try again. It does not have the same meaning as "enacted by the state", because there are a plurality of states. Each state has its own laws, independent from all of the others. Each gun law is enacted by *a* state.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy  +1 for ***the*** **state**. **By** in the OP's excerpt means "by ***each individual*** state" (50 of them) which make up the United States.

Answer (score 4):

**By** there refers to the organizing principle of the list or of the items in the set.

**Here are my 2015 expenses, (arranged) by month.**

```
January....$12,345.67
February...$11,519.44
March......$16,422.95
April .... 
...
```

-- But I don't want to see them by month. Can you show me the expenses *by category* instead?

**OK.**

```
Wining and Dining...........$15,244.11
Sports Tickets..............$26,245.16
Greens Fees.................$10,215.88
Travel......................$25,395.16
Overdue Library Book Fines..$53,218.77
```

**The animals boarded Noah's ark *by twos*.**

Comment: Yes. "By" here means "grouped by" or "organized by", not "passed by" in the sense that a law is passed. It would be equally meaningful to say, "Gun laws by date enacted", "Gun laws alphabetically by sponsor's name", etc.